# Remove .cs file in published asp.net webforms project

Tags: asp.net, publish

In the old asp.net project, there is a published .cs file in one of the folders. When I update the site, I update the .dll files, but this file is never updated. When I delete this .cs, the site does not work. How do I delete this file?

Comment: If the site doesn't work when you delete the file then you ***DO NOT DELETE*** the file. At least until you figure out the magic that is this file. Analyze the content, look for the filename references in the entire codebase, and even check your webserver to see if it's looking for this file.

Comment: when to update a site its usually the DLL and the aspx files that gets pushed the cs code should be in the dll. perhaps there is a reference to it somewhere, so a search also check the config file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a asp.net web site applcation to publish, or are you using a asp.net web site?

As a general rule, if you using asp.net web site applcation, then the source code files are NOT required to be up-loaded.

However, you left out one big detail. Where is that cs file? While a asp.net web site will attempt and does pre-compile all code, ONE BIG exception to this rule exists.

That is the folder app_code. That folder is in fact compiled by IIS, and as a result, if that file is in that folder, it will have to be included in your publish.

In fact, when I started using the newer Roslyn compiler (I liked it VERY much for allowing me to have longer free text such as SQL in the code as strings).

However, IIS did not and does not have Roslyn compile by default. And my  code was breaking.

So, as a result, I simple create my own folder called MyCode. And you could do the same. Note that each code module (vb.net) or static class for your general shared code routines do have to be marked manually as to compile.

eg this:

[image]

So, if your .cs file is in app_code, then you can move it out, drop it into a folder you create, and set the file build action to compile, and of course do not copy.

However, and this is a HUGE big "if". If your deployment model is web site as opposed to web site applcation, then this will not work, since IIS is doing your compile after deployment, as opposed to pre-compiling the code BEFORE deployment.

So, you are in luck if your .cs file is (or was) in app_code, since then as noted, you can move that out of app_code, and in properties set the file to be compiled, but not deployed. This as noted will only work if you deploying as a asp.net web site applcation as opposed to a asp.net web site.